# If we have a sequence $\{ s_n \}$, can we say the sequence $\{ \inf_{m\geq n}s_m \}$ converges to $s \leq $ all subsequential limits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was wondering if we have what's defined about. Can we simply say that the sequence  $\{ \inf_{m\geq n}s_m \}$ converges to $s \leq $ all subsequential limits of $s_n$ simply because the infimum is less or equal to every element of the sequence $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$? Assuming $\{ \inf_{m\geq n}s_m \}$ converges.

I feel like I need to add detail to make it more rigorous.

Comment: The inf is less than *or equal* to every *subsequent* element of the sequence.

Comment: @BrianO Assuming that it does converge?

Comment: Good, so I edited my comment after your edit. The limit of the inf's, when it exists, is called the *lim inf* of the sequence, denoted by $\lim \inf_n s_n$, and by $\underline{\lim}_n s_n$. If $(s_n)$ converges then $\underline{\lim}_n s_n = lim_n s_n$ -- that needs to be proved or cited. Also, if $(s_{n_k})$ is a subsequence, $\underline{\lim}_n (s_{n}) \le \underline{\lim}_k (s_{n_k})$ — this is easy to prove. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior.

Comment: And the only cases when the sequence of the infima does not converge are 1. when every infimum (or, equivalently, only the first infimum) is $-\infty$, that is, when the sequence $(s_n)$ is unbounded from below, and 2. when the infimum goes to $+\infty$, that is, when the sequence $(s_n)$ goes to $+\infty$